# Problem when implementing 'labelFontSize' property

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

I have been trying to add this code into my project:

```
reasonLabel.font = [UIFont labelFontSize:15];
```

but I keep getting this warning:

```
Class method '+labelWithSize:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

How would I fix this?

Thanks,

Seb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use with

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]
```

or

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
```

Answer (score 2):

[UIFont labelFontSize] returns the standard system UILabel font size, it is not an initializer. You must use something like fontWithSize:(CGFloat)fontSize or systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
reasonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: [UIFont labelFontSize]];
```

and if you want to create a smaller or bigger font, just add or subtract:

```
reasonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: [UIFont labelFontSize] + 2];
reasonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: [UIFont labelFontSize] - 1];
```

For **bold** fonts use this:

```
reasonLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: [UIFont labelFontSize]];
```